# Where is the local Google Drive folder?

Tags: google-apps

all.

I need to find the local directory for Google Drive. So far, all I see is the "virtual" folder in the sidebar.

I'm trying to do network transfers, but it won't recognize the sidebar folder.

Answer (score 5):

The Google Drive physical folder seems to be located in `~/Google Drive`.  You should be able to just go to your home folder and see it there.

If for some reason it is hidden, you can always get there by going to a finder window, pressing Command-Shift-G and then typing in `~/Google Drive` in the popup window.

Answer (score 1):

```
/Users/yourusername/Library/CloudStorage/yourGoogleAccountName
```

Comment: Sometime between April 5th 2016 and now, this seems to have become the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Zumi, it looks like it stores the local directory under the User folder.  So for the user 'maclover' it would be at /Users/maclover/Google Drive (or Google\ Drive because of the space).

JW